# onDataChange crash with Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am creating a summon simulator on my database app, and whenever I run it on my device and a few test devices, it works perfectly fine. However I published the app to the play store and now I keep seeing crash reports on the summon simulator and I am not sure how to fix it.

What the app should do, is when you click on summon simulator in the main activity, this menu opens up. When the activity starts, it gets the text in the selected radiobutton (lets say "one") and it then goes through the callData() loop for each ID, going from 1-126. If one of the IDs child "banners" has the value of "one", it then gets added to an array. It seems to work perfectly fine most of the time,

However when I am looking at crashylitics on firebase, its showing this error for a few people (44 people out of around 300):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
   at com.lukesapps.grandcross.database.summonSimulator$3.onDataChange(summonSimulator.java:535)
   at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:179)
   at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)
   at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
   at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

The database reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    ref.keepSynced(true);
```

Small sample of the raw JSON, each character is under a child which is an ID ranging from 1-126:

[ null, {

"banners" : "-",

"character" : "Zeldris (JP)",

"characterImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ds-grand-cross-database.appspot.com/o/zeldris2.png?alt=media&token=3f21e1bc-26eb-4bdc-aff6-1996346c6669",

"nameAndType" : "-",

"rarity" : "SSR",

}, {

"banners" : "-",

"character" : "Elizabeth (Goddess) (JP)",

"characterImage" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ds-grand-cross-database.appspot.com/o/goddess_elizabeth1.png?alt=media&token=177d18f9-405b-4961-b949-82afcc9fa450",

"nameAndType" : "Elizabeth (Goddess) (JP)Speed",

"type" : "Speed",

} ]

This is what I call when during onCreate and whenever someone changes the summoning banner:
characters is set as int characters = 2; before onCreate

```
public void callData() {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            characters = (int) count;
            for (int characterId = 1; characterId <= characters; characterId++) {
                String selectId = String.valueOf(characterId);
                DataSnapshot characterIdChild = dataSnapshot.child(selectId);
                String character = Objects.requireNonNull(characterIdChild.child("character").getValue()).toString();
                String characterName = Objects.requireNonNull(characterIdChild.child("nameAndType").getValue()).toString();
                String characterImage = Objects.requireNonNull(characterIdChild.child("characterImage").getValue()).toString();
                String characterRarity = Objects.requireNonNull(characterIdChild.child("rarity").getValue()).toString();
                /* ^ Where the crash occurs */
                String banners = Objects.requireNonNull(characterIdChild.child("banners").getValue()).toString();
                }
            }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There's **a lot** of code in there, and it's not clear what exact line it throwing the error. 1) I recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and applying that to isolate the problem to at most a dozen lines of code. 2) After that also add the relevant, minimal JSON that is needed to get the problem (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I agree with Frank however, within the 2nd line of your OnDataChange you have a variable called Characters...is that initialised outside of the object? If not it could be the source of your issue.